# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::useAsCallable()"

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I am getting the following error on a laravel site:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::useAsCallable() on line 72 of /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php

This only seems to happen on the staging server and I cannot reproduce on my local machine.  I have deleted the vendor directory and completely rebuilt it via composer, cleared all caches, ran composer dump-autoload and nothing seems to resolve it.

Digging into the source I can confirm that `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` extends `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and the method `useAsCallable()` exists in the extended class.  It is like it isnt loading it our something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which Laravel version?

Comment: What's the exact version? Also, can you paste the whole stack trace?

Comment: Also, try running `php artisan clear-compiled`

Comment: What action are you trying to do which creates this error?

Comment: This is on laravel 5.

Comment: Here is the full error from the logs

[2015-04-23 09:59:33] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::useAsCallable()' in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php:72
Stack trace:
#0 {main}

Answer (score 0):

Wierdly enough, I have noticed that most of such troubles from OctoberCMS arise out of 1 thing more often than not. -> FILE PERMISSIONS. This is especially true if using git to deploy.

set proper permissions: `sudo chmod -R 777 octoberProject/`
Then retry running the app.

Let us know if this helps.